# I have natural immunity to Hepatitis B. Do I pose risk to others?

Tags: blood-tests, liver, virus, infectious-diseases, hepatitis

Some time ago I was rejected as donor and received following rejection letter:

> Just wanted to inform you that there was a positive infectious disease
>   result for Hepatitis B. Unfortunately, we cannot take donors into the
>   program with a positive Hepatitis B test result due to the inventory
>   possibly being compromised.

And the following test results were attached to the rejection letter:

> Hepatitis Bc IgM Ab:                 NON-REACTIVE (Anti-HBc IgM)
>
> Hepatitis Bs Ag:                     NON-REACTIVE (HBsAg)
>
> Hepatitis Bc Ab:                     REACTIVE (HBcAb)

Obviously, I don't want to be a donor, if I pose risk to someone else. So I am fine with their judgment, if it is in best interest of others.

However, now I am curious, especially after I found [this CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/hepatitis/hbv/hbvfaq.htm#C2) website and I am trying to understand under which category I fall under.

**My understanding is that I fall under "Immune due to natural infection" and that it is actually impossible for me to infect others via sexual intercourse or if someone else uses my blood?**

Comment: EXCELLENT question, and welcome!

Comment: Did you copy your results correctly? The one reactive test, HBcAb, doesn't appear in the link you provided.

Comment: @CareyGregory I just double checked everything and yes, I have copied everything correctly. Could "HBcAb" be the same thing as "anti-HBc" that does show up in the table?

Answer (score 7):

The Hepatitis B core antibody test is positive for IgG but negative for IgM indicating that you had the hepatitis B infection a while ago. The negative hepatitis B surface antigen test means that they are not detecting the hepatitis B in your blood when testing for the virus surface antigen.  This means you've successfully cleared the infection to a very low level.  You don't mention the hepatitis B surface antibody levels which are usually used to determine if you're now immune eg. after a series of hepatitis B vaccinations.

This doesn't mean you don't have the virus in your system.  Immunosuppressants such as methotrexate and TNF inhibitors could still potentially reactivate the hepatitis B infection.  So, you'd want to measure the HBV DNA viral load and then track that serially to see if such treatment causes a reactivation.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24805974

Comment: Indeed, it seems that donor clinic did not do HBsAb (Hepatitis B Surface AntiBody test). However, I just stumbled across HBsAb tests I did long time ago with my general doctor and I have had HBsAb positive there. I guess this HBsAb positive proves that I am actually naturally immune, but the donor clinic does not care about HBsAb because they just don't want to take any risk?

Comment: Because it's not relevant to them. They have already established you have been infected.